# Image ordering tensor-flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am running the code for sliding window using tensor flow.

It is for Theano, that's why I am getting an error of image dimensions ordering.

Can anyone tell me how to amend it for tensor flow?

Error:

ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have shape (None, 224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3, 224, 224)

```
image=load_img('\e.jpg')
image= np.array(image).reshape((3264,5896,3))
image = image.astype('float32')
image /= 255
plt.imshow(image)
print(image.shape)


#%%SLIDING WINDOW
 ''
def find_a_object(image, step=224, window_sizes=[224]):
    boxCrack = 0  
    locations = []
    for win_size in window_sizes:
        #top = Y, left = X
        for Y in range(0, image.shape[0] - win_size + 1, step):
            for X in range(0, image.shape[1] - win_size + 1, step):
                # compute the (top, left, bottom, right) of the bounding box
                box = (Y, X, Y + win_size, X + win_size)

                #crop original image 
                cropped_img = image[box[0]:box[2], box[1]:box[3]]
                #reshape cropped image by window
                cropped_img = np.array(cropped_img).reshape((1,3,224,224))


                boxCrack = predict_function(cropped_img)

                if boxCrack ==0:
                    #print('box classified as crack') 
                    #save location of it                 
                    locations.append(box)
                    print("found")
        return locations
#%%FUNCTIONS
def predict_function(x):
    result =  model.predict_classes(x)
    if result==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1   
##SHOW CROPPED IMAGE
#def show_image(im):
#    plt.imshow(im.reshape((100,100,3)))
)

#DRAW BOXES FROM LOCATIONS when classified
def draw_boxes(image, locations):
    fix,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(image)       
    for l in locations:
        print (l)
        rectR = patches.Rectangle((l[1],l[0]),224,224,linewidth=1,edgecolor='R',facecolor='none'
        ax.add_patch(rectR)


#%%get locations from image
locations = find_a_object(image)

draw_boxes(image,locations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty clear, the ordering in TF should be `(None, dim_x, dim,_y, n_channels)`. I think transposing the image array as shown below should do the trick.

```
cropped_img = image[box[0]:box[2], box[1]:box[3]]
#reshape cropped image by window
cropped_img = np.array(cropped_img).reshape((1,3,224,224))
cropped_img = cropped_img.transpose(0,2,3,1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I get following error:
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: locations = find_a_object(image). When I run that line, it gives the error.

Comment: I can't really help with you without the code for `find_a_object`, but the error basically means you're checking the truth value of an array instead of a single value.

Comment: Thanks for your answers (and time). I already posted the code above. The 'find a object' is defined in the 7th line of the above code.

Comment: My bet is that the output of `model.predict()` (inside `predict_function`) is an array instead of a single value.